# Choose File names automatically based on a calculation and then import them to python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, import, filenames

I have run into a wall where I don't know how to proceed further. I generate a lot of Raw Data from my CFD simulations. All the raw data will be in text format. The format of the text file will be "hA-'timestep'.txt" where A equals 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. For Eg h1-0500.txt will refer to data obtained along h1 at 500th time step.All the files of hA will be saved in a single folder.  In my post processing, I want to import files at different **flow times** and do some analysis. I have written a code where it will calculate the timestep based on some equation which needs the flow time as user input.

What I would like to do is import all those files which correspond to the a particular **timestep** calculated through an equation.For Example, if I give an input of 2400 for the flow time, then the equation will give me time step as 16144. I want those file names which correspond to this time step to be automatically imported.Please see the below code.

I have uploaded the files corresponding to 16144. How do I choose the file name automatically based on the time step that is calculated. Currently after getting the time step from equation, I have to manually change the file name. I would really appreciate if some one could guide me on this. 
[Samplefiles](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hemqyerwu1fx6s7/AAAjnNIQ5DGQrtZvnnVXoBKXa?dl=0)

```
 # Notes about the Simulation#
 # Total No. of Time Steps completed = 16152
 # No. of Time Steps completed in HPC = 165
 # Flow Time before HPC = 3.1212s
 # Total Flow time of Fill Cycle = 2401.2s

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os

FT_init = 3.1212
delt = 0.15 # Timestep size
TS_init = 165 
flowtime = input("Enter the flow time required: ") # This is user input. Timestep will be calculated based on the flow time entered.
timestep = (flowtime-FT_init)/delt
timestep = round(timestep + TS_init)
print timestep 

def xlineplots(X1,Y1,V1,Tr1):
  plt.figure(1)
  plt.plot(X1,Tr1)
  plt.legend(['h0','h3','h5','h7','h9'],loc=0)
  plt.ylabel('Tracer Concentration')
  plt.xlabel('X (m)')
  plt.title('Tracer Concentration Variation along the Tank width')
  plt.figtext(0.6,0.6,"Flow Time = 2400s",style= 'normal',alpha = 0.5)
  plt.figtext(0.6,0.55,"Case: ddn110B",style= 'normal')
  plt.savefig('hp1.png', format='png', dpi=600) 

  plt.figure(2)
  plt.plot(X1,V1)
  plt.legend(['h0','h3','h5','h7','h9'],loc=0)
  plt.ylabel('V (m/s)')
  plt.xlabel('X (m)')
  plt.title('Vertical Velocity Variation along the Tank width')
  plt.figtext(0.6,0.6,"Flow Time = 2400s",style= 'normal',alpha = 0.5)
  plt.figtext(0.6,0.55,"Case: ddn110B",style= 'normal',alpha = 0.5)
  plt.savefig('hv1.png', format='png', dpi=600) 

 path1='Location of the Directory' # Location where the files are located 

 filename1=np.array(['h0-16144.txt','h3-16144.txt','h5-16144.txt','h7-16144.txt','h9-16144.txt'])

for i in filename1:
  format_name= i
  data1  = os.path.join(path1,format_name)
  data2 = np.loadtxt(data1,skiprows=1)
  data2 = data2[data2[:,1].argsort()]    
  X1 = data2[:,1]  # Assign x-coordinate from the imported text file
  Y1 = data2[:,2]  # Assign y-coordinate from the imported text file
  V1 = data2[:,4]  # Assign y-velocity from the imported text file
  Tr1 = data2[:,5] # Assign Tracer Concentration from the imported text file
  xlineplots(X1,Y1,V1,Tr1)
```

Error Message:

```
Enter the flow time required: 1250
8477
timestep: 8477

file(s) found:  ['E:/Fall2015/Research/CFD/ddn110B/Transfer/xline\\h0-8477.txt', 'E:/Fall2015/Research/CFD/ddn110B/Transfer/xline\\h1-8477.txt', 'E:/Fall2015/Research/CFD/ddn110B/Transfer/xline\\h2-8477.txt', 'E:/Fall2015/Research/CFD/ddn110B/Transfer/xline\\h3-8477.txt', 'E:/Fall2015/Research/CFD/ddn110B/Transfer/xline\\h4-8477.txt', 'E:/Fall2015/Research/CFD/ddn110B/Transfer/xline\\h5-8477.txt', 'E:/Fall2015/Research/CFD/ddn110B/Transfer/xline\\h6-8477.txt', 'E:/Fall2015/Research/CFD/ddn110B/Transfer/xline\\h7-8477.txt', 'E:/Fall2015/Research/CFD/ddn110B/Transfer/xline\\h8-8477.txt', 'E:/Fall2015/Research/CFD/ddn110B/Transfer/xline\\h9-8477.txt']
working in: E:/Fall2015/Research/CFD/ddn110B/Transfer/xline on: h0-8477
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-52-0503f720722f>", line 54, in <module>
    data2 = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=1)

  File "E:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 691, in loadtxt
    fh = iter(open(fname, 'U'))

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'h9-8477.txt'
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Looks like it found the `h1*`, `h2*` files just fine, but that you system did not generate the `h9*` one.  If you just wrap the `loadtxt` in a `try` block as I demonstrate, this should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got what you meant but it wasn't that clear. When the user inputs the timestep, then only the files corresponding to that timestep are loaded and used further with your plotting function:

I considered the following structure:

```
project/
| cfd_plot.py
+ sample/
| | h0-16144.txt
| | h1-16144.txt
| | h3-16144.txt
| | h0-25611.txt
| | h1-25611.txt
| | <...>
```

and here is `cfd_plot.py`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import re

# pth is a path for plt to save the image
def xlineplots(X1, Y1, V1, Tr1n, pth):
    _, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(X1, Tr1)
    ax.legend(['h0', 'h3', 'h5', 'h7', 'h9'], loc=0)
    ax.set_ylabel('Tracer Concentration')
    ax.set_xlabel('X (m)')
    ax.set_title('Tracer Concentration Variation along the Tank width')
    plt.figtext(.6, .6, "Flow Time = 2400s", style='normal', alpha=.5)
    plt.figtext(.6, .55, "Case: ddn110B", style='normal')
    plt.savefig(pth + '-hp1.png', format='png', dpi=600)

    _, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(X1, V1)
    ax.legend(['h0', 'h3', 'h5', 'h7', 'h9'], loc=0)
    ax.set_ylabel('V (m/s)')
    ax.set_xlabel('X (m)')
    ax.set_title('Vertical Velocity Variation along the Tank width')
    plt.figtext(.6, .6, "Flow Time = 2400s", style='normal', alpha=.5)
    plt.figtext(.6, .55, "Case: ddn110B", style='normal', alpha=.5)
    plt.savefig(pth + '-hv1.png', format='png', dpi=600)


FT_init = 3.1212
delt = .15  # Timestep size
TS_init = 165
flowtime = input("Enter the flow time required: ")

timestep = (int(flowtime) - FT_init) / delt
timestep = round(timestep + TS_init)

reps = ['sample']  # location where the files are located

# first simple version
# files = []
# for rep in reps:  # recursive search for the files that match the timestep
#     for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rep):
#         for filename in [f for f in filenames if str(timestep) in f and f.endswith('.txt')]:
#             files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

# second version, using regular expressions
reg_exp = '^.*-({:d})\.txt'.format(timestep)

files = []
for rep in reps:  # recursive search for the files that match the timestep
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rep):
        for filename in [f for f in filenames if re.search(reg_exp, f)]:
            files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

print('timestep:', timestep)
print('file(s) found: ', files)

for file in files:
    directory = os.path.dirname(file)  # directory of the .txt file
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]  # basename of the .txt file
    print('working in:', directory, 'on:', name)

    data2 = np.loadtxt(file, skiprows=1)
    data2 = data2[data2[:, 1].argsort()]
    X1 = data2[:, 1]  # Assign x-coordinate from the imported text file
    Y1 = data2[:, 2]  # Assign y-coordinate from the imported text file
    V1 = data2[:, 4]  # Assign y-velocity from the imported text file
    Tr1 = data2[:, 5]  # Assign Tracer Concentration from the imported text file

    # here you can give directory + name or just name to xlineplots
    xlineplots(X1, Y1, V1, Tr1, os.path.join(directory, name))
    # xlineplots(X1, Y1, V1, Tr1, name)
```

**UPDATE**: made some edits (comments)

**UPDATE2**: using regular expressions on file search, the filter is `'^.*-({:d})\.txt'.format(timestep)`:

```
^      match beginning of the line
.*     match any character (except newline), zero or multiple times
-      match the character -
({:d}) match the timestep, formatted as an integer
\.     match the character .
txt    match characters txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply. When I try to execute the program, it shows me an invalid \x escape error. Also in the def xlineplots function, there is a term "pth" which is not defined any where in the code. Also I request you to put some comments in the code as it will easier for me to understand the code. I don't have the required reputation to accept your answer.

Comment: pth is defined when the call to xlineplots is issued:
xlineplots(X1, Y1, V1, Tr1, os.path.join(directory, name)), in this case:
pth=os.path.join(directory, name)

Comment: Thank you neok. I really appreciate your guidance. I am running into a issue. If I give an input for flow time as 25, then my time step calculated is 310. But If I run the program, it is considering all the files which has 310 in them, i.e h1-9310,h1-12310,h1-4310 etc. But it has to consider only h1-0310.txt, h2-0310, h2-0310.txt files. Also it is not considering files starting with h9. Is there a limitation in the code. Please forgive me if some of questions are silly. I am a beginner to python.

Comment: Right now the filtering of the file is ensured with if str(timestep) in f and f.endswith('.txt') ...
If you want a stronger filter consider using regular expression eg for our example: see https://regex101.com/r/vQ1jZ1/3
the condition now becomes re.search(reg_exp, f), means search for the pattern reg_exp in f, and if there is a match then append filename to the list of files

Comment: Thank you neok. Now I understood your code. I have updated the error message that I am getting when I run the file. It seems that the code cannot find any files starting with h9. I can confirm that the files starting with h9 are actually present in the folder

Comment: I think there is an issue with the loop of "for file in files:". The program runs fine until it comes to the loop. It is listing all the correct files in the directory.

Comment: You are right there was an error with the code, I edited it :
in the for loop, I replaced this: data2 = np.loadtxt(file, skiprows=1)

Answer (score 2):

Is the issue with generating file names, or finding file names that match a certain pattern?

I could rework your code with:

```
hs = [0,3,5,7,9]
timestep = 16144
filenames = ['h%s-%s'%(h, timestep) for h in hs]

for name in filenames:
    fname = op.path.join(path1, name)
    try:
        data = np.loadtxt(fname, skiprows=1)
    except IOError:
        # cannot open this file, most likely because it does not exist
        # continue with the next
        continue  
    ...
```

Here I'm generating filenames with the desired format, and loading and using each one, if possible.

I could do searches with `glob` or `re` applied to directory listings, but there's nothing wrong with my `try-except` approach.  It is good Python style.

========================

Here's an example of using `glob` (in an Ipython session):

First a testdir with bunch of files (created with `touch):

```
In [9]: ls testdir
h1-123.txt  h12-1234.txt  h2-123.txt  h2-124.txt  h3-124.txt  h343.txt

In [10]: import glob
```

general search for files starting with `h`, ending with `.txt`:

```
In [11]: glob.glob('testdir/h*.txt')
Out[11]: 
['testdir/h2-124.txt',
 'testdir/h3-124.txt',
 'testdir/h12-1234.txt',
 'testdir/h343.txt',
 'testdir/h1-123.txt',
 'testdir/h2-123.txt']
```

narrow it to ones with 2 fields separated by dash

```
In [12]: glob.glob('testdir/h*-*.txt')
Out[12]: 
['testdir/h2-124.txt',
 'testdir/h3-124.txt',
 'testdir/h12-1234.txt',
 'testdir/h1-123.txt',
 'testdir/h2-123.txt']
```

restrict the 1st field to single character

```
In [13]: glob.glob('testdir/h?-*.txt')
Out[13]: 
['testdir/h2-124.txt',
 'testdir/h3-124.txt',
 'testdir/h1-123.txt',
 'testdir/h2-123.txt']
```

for a specific 'time' string:

```
In [14]: glob.glob('testdir/h?-123.txt')
Out[14]: ['testdir/h1-123.txt', 'testdir/h2-123.txt']
```

The search string could be created with  string formatting

```
In [15]: times=123
In [16]: glob.glob('testdir/h?-%s.txt'%times)
```

========================

With `os` and `re` I could search like:

```
In [28]: import os
In [29]: import re
In [30]: filelist=os.listdir('./testdir')
In [31]: [n for n in filelist if re.match('h[1-9]-123',n) is not None]
Out[31]: ['h1-123.txt', 'h2-123.txt']
```

======================

If the file names have to have 4 digits (or whatever) in the name then use something like:

```
'h%d-%04d'%(3,123)   # 'h3-0123'
'testdir/h?-%04d.txt'%times
```

You need this sort of padding regardless of whether you use the `try`, `glob` or `re`.

[Add zeros as prefix to a calculated value based on the number of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873139/add-zeros-as-prefix-to-a-calculated-value-based-on-the-number-of-digits)

Comment: This is about finding files that match a certain pattern. The files are of the pattern hA-'BBBBB'.txt where A is from 0 to 9 in steps of 1 and BBBBB refers to the time step. I will be giving BBBBB as a user input and I want the code to find all the text files matching BBBBB in a folder

Comment: I added a `glob` example.