# Add zeros as prefix to a calculated value based on the number of digits

Tags: python, numpy

I have written an expression which will ask for a user input. Based on the user input, it will calculate a value. If the calculated value is say 1, then I want the value to be converted to 0001. Same thing applies when the calculated value is 2 and 3 digits long.

If the calculated value is 4 or 5 digits long, then I don't want any modification on it. This value is used in the later part of the program which I have not mentioned here.

```
import numpy as np

FT_init = 3.1212
delt = 0.15
TS_init = 165
flowtime = input("Enter the flow time required: ")
timestep = (flowtime-FT_init)/delt
timestep = round(timestep + TS_init)
print timestep
```

I request your help on this.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to print it that way?

Comment: Not really. I want the value to be converted that way. Say my time step calculated is 263, then I want the value to be converted to 0263. If it is 25, then 0025. But If the timestep calculated is 2569, then I don't want to modify it. Same applies when the time step calculated is 5 digits long.

Comment: Does this later use expect an integer or a string?

Comment: @hpaulj This timestep value will be used to identify text files which will be imported into python. For Eg. if the time step value is 8500, then the text files h0-8500.txt, h1-8500,txt etc. corresponding to the timestep value will be imported and further analysis done on that data.

Comment: So this is a spin off of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33861074/choose-file-names-automatically-based-on-a-calculation-and-then-import-them-to-p?  Then use one of the string formatting suggestions later when you construct the file name(s).  Numbers (integers) don't have leading zeros, just their string representation.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes this question is related to my previous post. The files are already generated from the CFD tool. Each of these files will have a timestep associated with them. So that's why I wanted only those files which matched the timestep calculated from the above expression to be imported into Python.

Comment: Format the file name with something like: `'h%d-%04d'%(3,123)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use zfill() string method:

```
str(timestep).zfill(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less similar to the other answer.

```
i = 9
print("{:05d}".format(i))
```

Comment: Thank you Ayush for the reply. Your suggestion worked, but I don't want to just print the timestep, I want the time step calculated to have the required number of digits

Answer (score 0):

just change the print to use a format string:

```
print '%04d' % int(timestep)
```

that will zero fill left, and allow it to show 5 digits without problem

however you cannot use that output in any kind of calculations since converting back to a number will strip the left zeros and possibly use it as an octal number - which will cause a conversion error if there are digits that would not be valid octal i.e. 0397

Answer (score 0):

Use the [string.format() method](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#formatspec). The following format specification, `'{:04}'`, says replace that with the argument `n` from `format(n)` and then format it, `:`, with leading zeros, `0`, printing at least 4, `4`, digits.

Example with numbers of different printed widths:

```
for n in [1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 123456]:
    print('{:04}'.format(n))
```

Output:

```
0001
0012
0123
1234
12345
123456
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit it would be more helpful to later users